# Google sheet formula to find missing number based on matching criteria

Tags: google-sheets

With the data in the attached google sheet, Col F (IN/OUT) will have either IN or OUT and Col J (Bag Numbers) will have numbers seperated by Comma.

Based on the sample data, for Vendor 4-Sunil, Bag numbers 2,3,4,5 where sent OUT on 8/9/21. On 17/9/21, 2,3,4,5 where received IN. So there is nothing Pending with Vendor 4-Sunil.

On the other hand with Vendor 5-Rajan, Bag numbers 13,14,15,16 where sent OUT on 14/9/21. On 25/9/21 Bag Numbers 13,15 where received IN. So the pending bags yet to be received IN from Vendor 5-Rajan is 14,16.

Is there a way to build a formula in Google sheet to indicate the number of pending Bags based on IN or OUT criteria for a given Vendor?

Thank you.

Sample Google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10XP3k4HLteGHgOEdd0YIZR-_0p2IiHog5R7luIM5NeM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display Bag numbers out, try:

```
=arrayformula(query({
query({A:J},"select Col5 where Col5 !='' and Col6 contains 'OUT' order by Col5",1),
regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(query({A:J},"select Col10 where Col5 !='' and Col6 contains 'OUT' order by Col5",1),iferror(vlookup(query({A:J},"select Col5 where Col5 !='' and Col6 contains 'OUT' order by Col5",1),{query({A:I,iferror(regexreplace(J:J,",","|"),J:J)},"select Col5, Col10 where Col5 !='' and Col6 contains 'IN' order by Col5",1)},2,0)),""),",+",","),"^,+|,+$",)
},"where Col2 != '' label Col2 'Remaining out' ",1))
```

[image]

If you want a more complex solution running from a single cell that handles multiple OUT and IN for the same Vendor, then try:

```
=arrayformula({"Vendor","Items still out";regexreplace(query({
query(regexreplace(split(flatten(regexreplace(trim(query(transpose(query(if(E2:E<>"",substitute({E2:E&char(9998)&F2:F&char(9998),J2:J,J2:J}," ",char(9999)),),"select Col1,Max(Col2) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 pivot Col3",)),"",9^9))," ",",")),char(9998)),"^,+|,+$",),"select Col1 where Col2 contains 'OUT' order by Col1",0),
iferror(regexreplace(regexreplace(query(regexreplace(split(flatten(regexreplace(trim(query(transpose(query(if(E2:E<>"",substitute({E2:E&char(9998)&F2:F&char(9998),J2:J,J2:J}," ",char(9999)),),"select Col1,Max(Col2) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 pivot Col3",)),"",9^9))," ",",")),char(9998)),"^,+|,+$",),"select Col3 where Col2 contains 'OUT' order by Col1",0),iferror(vlookup(
query(regexreplace(split(flatten(regexreplace(trim(query(transpose(query(if(E2:E<>"",substitute({E2:E&char(9998)&F2:F&char(9998),J2:J,J2:J}," ",char(9999)),),"select Col1,Max(Col2) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 pivot Col3",)),"",9^9))," ",",")),char(9998)),"^,+|,+$",),"select Col1 where Col2 contains 'OUT' order by Col1",0),
{regexreplace(query(regexreplace(split(flatten(regexreplace(trim(query(transpose(query(if(E2:E<>"",substitute({E2:E&char(9998)&F2:F&char(9998),J2:J,J2:J}," ",char(9999)),),"select Col1,Max(Col2) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 pivot Col3",)),"",9^9))," ",",")),char(9998)),"^,+|,+$",),"where Col2 contains 'IN' order by Col1",0),",","|")}
,3,0),),),"^,+|,+$",),)
},"where Col2 !='' ",0),char(9999)," ")})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Aresvik. It gives the total count but does not specify the bag numbers.  Happy with what I got but if the Bag Numbers can be specified it would be brilliant.

I have updated the sheet (Sample Google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10XP3k4HLteGHgOEdd0YIZR-_0p2IiHog5R7luIM5NeM/edit?usp=sharing)with what is expected.

Thanks again

Comment: In case your source data is mixed up, I've added a new solution to show bags still out.

Comment: Thank you @Aresvik.

Works as expected and perfect result.

Comment: In case you have multiple OUT and IN for the same vendor, I've added a more robust solution.

Comment: Brilliant Solution. Good thinking. That was so useful. Yes there are multiple OUT and IN for the same vendor.

Comment: a kind request to expand the formula to include another column to SUM the quantity  based on the Bag Numbers if possible.

Comment: Based on bag number still out? Show me a pic of how you see it looking on the page, and I'll see what's involved. The formula is quite complex to alter.